# How do I make part of a string lowercase in python?

Tags: python, string, split, lowercase

I am trying to take a string that is about a paragraph long and lowercase all of the words in it that are not completely uppercase. "The QUICK brown fOx" should print as "the QUICK brown fox" after this function. It seems to not change anything, but it does leave the words that are all caps. How would I lowercase a word in a string and return it to the string?

```
def AllCaps(string):
for word in string.split(' '):
    if word.isupper()==True:
        pass
    else:
        word = word.lower()
print(string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your current code does is rebind the `word` variable, so that instead of `'fOx'` it now holds `'fox'`. That has no effect on the original `string` variable.

You could print out each word as you get it:

```
for word in string.split(' '):
    # your existing code
    print(word, end=' ')
```

Or, maybe better, you could accumulate all of the words into a list, join them back into a string, and print that:

```
words = []
for word in string.split(' '):
    # your existing code
    words.append(word)
print(' '.join(words))
```

Comment: I see you were the victim of the phantom downvoter also

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Yeah, at first I thought it was someone who didn't like the question and thought we were answering a help vampire, but given that he didn't vote to close, flag, downvote, or comment on the question… no clue. There are always a few inexplicable voters on this site, I've stopped trying to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is sort of working, but you're throwing away the result. You should append them to a different string, then print that string. For example:

```
def allCaps(string):
    newString = ''
    for word in string.split(' '):
        if word.isupper()==True:
            newString += word + ' '
        else:
            newString += word.lower() + ' '
    print(newString)

allCaps('The QUICK brown fOx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If a word is all caps `x.isupper()` will be True else just convert to lower and join:

```
def All_caps(s):
    return " ".join([x if x.isupper() else x.lower() for x in s.split() ])

In [34]: all_caps("The QUICK brown fOx")#
Out[34]: 'the QUICK brown fox'
```

It is  better to avoid using string as a variable name as it is a builtin module, also if `word.isupper()==True` can be written  as and is equivalent to `if word.isupper()`

You should in general use `split()` without any parameters to split on an arbitrary amount of whitespace or else you may sometimes not get the output you expect:

```
In [5]: s= "foo    bar"

In [6]: s.split(" ")
Out[6]: ['foo', '', '', '', 'bar']


In [7]: s.split()
Out[7]: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: In this case, I think `split(' ')` actually makes more sense—because then `' '.join` will get back exactly his original string, instead of his original string with all runs of whitespace converted to a single space character.

Comment: @abarnert, I was talking in a general sense, e.g                                     `a,b ="foo     bar".split(" ")` where there is two spaces between foo and bar

Comment: Sure, there are more cases where `split()` is useful than `split(' ')` (which is probably why the former is the default in the first case…). But this seems to be one of the uncommon cases where it's not.